# Init polymer attributes before ready()

Tags: polymer, custom-component

When dynamically creating polymer elements in js, how to initialize attributes before ready() event?
my code below:

```
var el = document.createElement("my-elem");
el.setAttribute("myAttr", 123); // or el.myAttr = 123.
```

the ready() event is fired before myAttr is set. actually I want it works like it does in HTML way:

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.innerHTML('<my-elem myAttr="123"></my-elem>');
var el = div.children[0];
```

in this way, myAttr is set when ready() event working, but the code is kinda ugly. is there a way like this:

```
var el = document.createElement("my-elem", { myAttr: 123});
```

Comment: Why would you ever want assertion before ready event?

Comment: The ready() event happen just after you create the element, so the behaviour you see is normal, even if not intended for you. Can I ask why the ready() event is so important? You have other lifecycle events that you could use, https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods : domReady(), attributeChanged()...

Comment: @LostInBrittany and Mohammand, I need ready() because I want to init internal states which depend on all published attributes are set. eg, you want to call your own create() method which depend on myAttrA, myAttrB. if you call create() in ready(), it's good for HTML way but for JS way. For now my solution is calling create() after all setAttributes in JS and call it in ready() as well for sometimes it is used in HTML way, a boolean variable "isCreated" is needed for avoiding create() get called multiply times.