# Imperatively setting attribute to declaratively created child element before ready in Polymer

Tags: polymer

Similar to this question, [Init polymer attributes before ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543950/init-polymer-attributes-before-ready), but not quite the same.

Is it possible to imperatively set attribute of a child element in Polymer before the ready event of that child element fires?

https://plnkr.co/edit/fM7lAflOLWOFuIiE7e9q?p=preview

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
    <link href="user-profile.html" rel="import">
  </head>

  <body>
    <user-profile></user-profile>
  </body>

</html>
```

user-profile.html:

```
<link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="address-card.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="user-profile">
  <template>
    <address-card address$="{{address}}"></address-card>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "user-profile",
      properties: {
        address: {
          type: String,
          value: "Pass the value to the child"
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

address-card.html:

```
<link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="address-card">
  <template>
    {{content}}
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "address-card",
      properties: {
        address: String
      },
      ready: function () {
        alert(this.address);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `<user-profile>`, pass the value `{{primaryAddress}}` to his child the element `<address-card>`. The element `<user-profile>` is a "mediator" that control/assing value to his child.

```
 <dom-module id="user-profile">
      <template>
        …
        <address-card address="{{address}}"></address-card>
      </template>
      … 
      properties: {
          address: {
          type: String,
          value: "Pass the value to the child"
          }
         }
    </dom-module>
```

Comment: I've completed your example and added it to the question, https://plnkr.co/edit/fM7lAflOLWOFuIiE7e9q?p=preview After following the link, an alert will say `undefined` instead of "Pass the value to the child".

Comment: user-profile.html // address$="{{address}}" --) address="{{address}}"

Comment: Sh**! I don't need attribute binding!

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I use the data binding system to pass the value from the parent to the child.

[Linking paths with data bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#paths)

Comment: That doesn't work. Ready on the child is fired before the property of the parent is set. Do I need to write an example?